# Catch bluetooth connect event while app is in background/closed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following some of code examples I found to achieve this, but it doesn't seem to work. I enabled "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" in plist file.

```
@objc(StartStop) class StartStop : CDVPlugin,CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral){
        print("MLOG Did connect!!")
    }

    override func pluginInitialize(){
        print("MLOG initialize : ")
         centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
```

I get events for `centralManagerDidUpdateState` and `didDiscover`, but nothing for connecting/disconnecting device. This doesn't even work with app in foreground, I haven't yet got to testing it in closed/background mode.

Comment: Are you issuing a `connect` call after you discover the peripheral?  If so, are you keeping a strong reference to the peripheral in a property?  Show that code.

Comment: I'm not connecting it on my own. I was under the impression that I will catch event when phone automatically connects to the device.

Comment: No.  Core Bluetooth allows your app to discover and connect to Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) peripherals.  You will only get a `didConnect` delegate callback after your app makes a connection to a peripheral.  It is nothing to do with connections made by any other app or connections of legacy peripherals, such as audio devices, to the device.

Comment: All-right. Is there a way to trigger my application code when a peripheral is connected/disconnected ?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: On Android I can register receiver that triggers my code for a specific bluetooth event even when my app is closed or in background. Are you certain I can't get this functionality on iOS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196564/discussion-between-paulw11-and-somerandomusername).